# How to keep online in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I used robocopy batch script in Windows Vista.

It takes about an hour.

This script can't use in Windows7, because it turns offline about 5 minutes later.

Can I keep online in this batch script ?

Comment: What's turning offline? That's not normal behavior for anything.

Comment: remote folder is restricted by group policy.it is usually offline and I can make it online for 5 minutes by explore's 'online' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is:
Why does the console window in which the robocopy script run stays on my screen for an hour when I execute it in my Vista machine, but closes automatically within five minutes when I execute it in my Win7 machine.

If that is the case, I believe it is due to some error that led to script to end it's execution and closing the prompt. It usually closes if you run the script by clicking on it and the script is done executing.

To figure out the error, you should try running CMD application (the windows command line tool). Run CMD.exe.

Then navigate to the folder where your script is located.

Run the script via command line.

Check if there is any error messages on the screen and edit your question, adding the error message.

If this is not what you meant, please add more info to your question.

Comment: thank you for replying for my problem,but the situation is a bit different. In win7 ,robocopy works fine at first,but 'The system cannot find the file specified.' or 'The network path was not found.' are printed in terminal after five minutes later.

Comment: this trouble is resolved.It's due to network trouble.Thank you.